# replace function doesnt replace words

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
      lyrics = lyrics.replace(/lyrics|lyric|lyrical|official music video|audio|official|official video|official video hd|official hd video|offical video music|extended|hd|(\[.+\])/gi, "");
```

if i put **Bastilles & Marshmello - Happier (Official Music Video)** in place of **await getLyrics(song.url)** i want to replace **(Official Music Video)** along with the parantheses. How do i do that as my code is not replacing them. And i also want to remove all those words(if those words are there in a song title) and not only **(Official Music Video)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the parantheses with `\`:

```js
let lyrics = "Hello (Official Music Video)"
lyrics = lyrics.replace(/lyrics|lyric|lyrical|official music video|\(official music video\)|audio|official|official video|official video hd|official hd video|offical video music|\(offical video music\)|extended|hd|(\[.+\])/gi, "");

console.log(lyrics)
```